# A question about $\lim_{n\to\infty} (1+\frac{1}{n})^n = e$ with 1 replaced.

Tags: limits

$\lim_{n\to\infty} (1+\frac{1}{n})^n = e$, $\lim_{n\to\infty} (x+\frac{1}{n})^n=0,x\in(0,1)$

How come that the second limit goes to 0? If it goes to 0, shouldn't the first one go to 1?

I am thinking that for the second one to go to 0 is that 1/n goes to 0 then x^n goes to zero, and for the first the same but 1^n goes to 1 when n goes to inf.

Comment: So what? $\lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{x\to 1}$ does not give the same value as $\lim_{x\to 1}\lim_{n\to\infty}$. Is that what's bothering you? This may not be the simplest example to see that it is true. But it is, nonetheless, something you must just learn to accept.

Comment: "If it goes to 0, shouldn't the first one also go to 1?" What's your reasoning here?

Comment: No, it is that say x=1 in the second limit, then the limit would go to e, but for 0<x<1 then it goes to 0, I dont understand why that is.

Comment: I wrote it wrong.

Comment: So you want someone to prove the second limit to you?  Well, intuitively, the base doesn't go towards $1$. Once $n$ is large enough, the base will be smaller than $1$ by some fixed margin, while the exponent just keeps increasing. That immediately means that the limit is $0$.

Comment: You have to clarify what your question is. As it stands, users make of it what they want and e.g. prove you one of those limits. It seems you know that already.

Comment: Note that even something as simple as $x^n$ goes to $0$ when $|x|<1$ and to $1$ when $x=1$, so the parameterized limit $x\mapsto \lim_{n\to\infty} x^n$ fails to be continuous in the domain where the sequence converges. Adding $\frac1n$ to the base should be expected to make anything behave _nicer_.

Comment: What is your reasoning for why if for $0<x<1$ it goes to $0$, it should go to $0$ for $x=1$ as well?

Comment: your right, that was not what I was thinking, I am going to make it clear.

Comment: @potete I have changed my answer to reflect the new question. I hope I have captured your reasoning and what my response to it would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the logarithm of your sequence and compute its limit:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}n\log\left(x+\frac{1}{n}\right)=
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{\log(x+t)}{t}
$$
provided the latter limit exists. Now $\log(x+t)=\log x+\log(1+t/x)$ and the further substitution $u=t/x$ yields
$$
\lim_{u\to0^+}\frac{\log x+\log(1+u)}{ux}=-\infty
$$
because the numerator has limit $\log x<0$.

By continuity of the exponential,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(x+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\!n}=0
$$

The same argument tells us that, for $x>1$, the limit is $\infty$.

Comment: Isnt x fixed so why does the limit of log x matter? I dont see the reason for the third limit to go to negative infinity. If you could explain I would be happy, for its a good explanation.

Comment: @potete Yes, $x$ is fixed and its logarithm is negative. So the numerator has limit $\log x$ and the denominator has limit $0$ (by positive values). Hence the limit is $-\infty$.

Answer (score 5):

If $x<y<1$ then for large enough $n$,$$x+\frac{1}{n}<y$$ so the limit is $$<y^n\to 0$$

Answer (score 2):

I think for $x\in(0,1)$ it goes to $0$ because there is $\epsilon>0$ and $0<q<1$, for which for all $n>\epsilon$ $x+\frac{1}{n}<q$ and $q^n$ goes to $0$.

We can take $q=\frac{x+1}{2}$ for example.

Comment: @potete I also added something. See now.

Answer (score 2):

We have

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(x+\frac 1n)^n = \lim_{n\to\infty}x^n(1+\frac {1/x}n)^n = \lim_{n\to\infty}x^n \lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{1/x}{n})^n =  e^{1/x}\lim_{n\to\infty}x^n$$

and thus for $x>1$ the limit is $+\infty$, for $0<x<1$ the limit is $0$ and for $x=1$ the limit is $e$, as expected.

Answer (score 2):

If $x<1$ then you can find some $N$ such that $x+\frac{1}{N} <1$.

Set $y =x+\frac{1}{N}$.

Then, for all $n >N$ you have 
$$x^n < (n+\frac{1}{n})^n <y^n$$
and, as $0<x<y<1$ 
$$\lim x^n=\lim y^n=0$$

Therefore
$$\lim_n (x+\frac{1}{n})^n=0$$
by squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Another way, same idea as to prove that the first one tends to $e$
$$
\left(x+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}=x^n\left(1+\frac{1}{nx}\right)^n=x^ne^{n\ln\left(1+ 1/nx\right)}
$$
Then
$$
\left(x+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}\underset{n \rightarrow +\infty}{\sim}x^n e^{1/x}
$$
$x$ is fixed and $x \in \left]0,1\right[$, hence $\ x^n \underset{n \rightarrow +\infty}{\rightarrow}0$ so
$$
\left(x+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}\underset{n \rightarrow +\infty}{\rightarrow}0
$$

Answer (score 1):

Rene Schipperus has also answered why the limit is $0$ if $x \in (0,1)$. In particular the reason is *not* that $\frac{1}{n}$ approaches $0$, so $(x+\frac{1}{n})^n$ has the same limit as $x^n$. Instead, the reason is that we can eventually bound $(x+\frac{1}{n})^n$ away from $1$ by some $y^n$, which we know goes to $0$.

For all $0\leq x<1$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}x^n = 0$; for all $x>1$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}x^n = \infty$. In the case of $(1 + \frac{1}{n})^n$, if we could bound it below away from $1$ by some $y^n$ with $y>1$, we could conclude the limit is $\infty$. But we cannot do that. We can bound below by $1$, but then all we can say is that the limit is somewhere between $1$ and $\infty$. So the bounding method used for $x \in (0,1)$ does not extend to the $x=1$ case.

Answer (score 1):

Let $n>\frac{2}{1-x}$. Then $x+\frac{1}{n}\leq \frac{x+1}{2}<1.$ So for $n$ large, $$(x+1/n)^n\leq \left(\frac{x+1}{2}\right)^n$$

But since $0<\frac{x+1}{2}<1$, we have $\left(\frac{x+1}{2}\right)^n\to 0$.

Alternatively, if you know that $\left(1+\frac{a}{n}\right)^n\to e^a$ for any $a$, then:

$$\left(x+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n = x^n\left(1+\frac{1/x}n\right)^n$$

and $x^n\to 0$ and $\left(1+\frac{1/x}n\right)^n\to e^{1/x}.$ so the product converges to zero.

This second approach gives you a nice upper bound for the terms, since $(1+a/n)^n$ is increasing as $n$ increases, when $a$ is positive, so $(x+1/n)^n\leq x^ne^{1/x}.$